# Unity integrated React native app game doesnt play with yarn android

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine

I have a mobile app that works well and recently we integrated a unity game in the app. Whenever we do yarn android and run the game within the app. It gives error

```
not enough storage space to install required resources
```

However if i create apk or runs from android simulator the app and hence the game works fine.

Please can anyone tell me the solution and reason behind why this is happening.